# Unity performance drain of non-visible UI

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I've got a game with lots of menus. The menus have their own scripts which I don't neccessarily want to stop, just because the user can't see the menu.

This is why I currently just translate the canvases off the screen, so the user can't see them and the scripts can continue to do their thing.

Can anyone say something about the performance drain of non-visible UI? Does it cost much to have let's say 200 labels, 50 images and 50 buttons active but off screen, or is it all culled away immediately and does basically nothing performance wise?

In this context I'm also curious, if it is ok to have multiple fullscreen menus in the same canvas as I do currently, or would it be way better to give each menu it's own canvas? If non-visible UI drains a lot of performance while not visible, I would do the latter option to deactivate the canvas, but keep the script running. Would that be the way to go?

Comment: Just because it's off screen doesn't mean that its update function is not being called.  You're probably saving almost nothing. Granted you don't have to draw on the screen, but you still have to store them in memory, and call there active functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm, that there was a huge performance increase after deactivating the UI elements, that are not shown. To keep scripts on them alive, one can just write a little function, that checks if there are any scripts on a GameObject that is about to be deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

The performance is really poor. Even rendering operations are being called as long as they are active, doesn't matter how hidden of far from the camera.

It's better to have just one canvas, rather than a lot of them.

Comment: Well now you basically said that it's bad to have multiple canvases, but you also implied that it is bad to have just one canvas, by saying that the performance is poor if there are many things that will be rendered, even if the camera is not showing them.

Comment: You can de activate the game objects. Inactive game objects won't affect your performance.

Comment: "The menus have their own scripts which I don't neccessarily want to stop, just because the user can't see the menu."

Comment: Then maybe it's a good idea to put the script in another object, and leave the UI object for the visual aspect